# Object in jquery widget behaving as only one instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I've been developing a jQuery widget using the widget factory.

All is well except I've noticed that if I instantiate the widget on more then one DOM element on the same page, any object within the widget is shared between the DOM elements EXCEPT for the options object.

I thought that all objects and functions had their own instance within the widget. I'm obviously missing something and would appreciate some guidance.

For example:

```
(function($) {
  $.widget("a07.BearCal", {
    options: { className : "test" },
    _glbl: { something: "" },
    _create: function() {
      this._glbl.something = this.element.attr('class');
      this.options.className = this.element.attr('class');
    },
  });
})(jQuery);

// Instantiate widget on .full
$('.full').BearCal();

//Should output full
console.log($('.full').data('BearCal')._glbl.something);

//Should output full
console.log($('.full').data('BearCal').options.className);

// Instantiate widget on .mini
$('.mini').BearCal();

//Should output mini
console.log($('.mini').data('BearCal')._glbl.something);

//Should output mini
console.log($('.mini').data('BearCal').options.className);

//Should output full but outputs mini
console.log($('.full').data('BearCal')._glbl.something);

//Should output full
console.log($('.full').data('BearCal').options.className);​
```

Working example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/NrKVP/4/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of your widget:

```
$.widget("a07.BearCal", {
  // The stuff in here...
});
```

get attached to your widget's prototype. The widget factory knows about `options` and knows that it needs to duplicate them per-widget: your `options` are behaving as you expect because the widget factory arranges for this behavior. The widget factory doesn't know anything about `_glbl` so it gets left on the prototype and thus shared by all instances of your widget.

You can duplicate your `_glbl` yourself if you want per-widget copies:

```
  this._glbl = { something: this.element.attr('class') };
```

That will give you a different `_glbl` object on each widget.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UX5Zg/

If your `_glbl` is more complicated, then you can use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to copy it and merge `something` in:

```
this._glbl = $.extend(
  { },
  this._glbl,
  { something: this.element.attr('class') }
);
```

You'll want to use `true` as the first argument to `$.extend` if you need a deep copy. The empty object, `{ }`, is needed as `$.extend` will merge everything into its first object argument and you want a fresh copy.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pyUmz/1/

Comment: Makes perfect sense. However, as an extension to the original question, why does the 'something' object in the following example not behave the same? The only difference is it's not nested within another object. http://jsfiddle.net/NrKVP/11/

Comment: Because that `something` is set directly on the object (`this.something = ...`) but `this._glbl` isn't on `this`, it comes from `this`'s prototype. Add `console.log('---->', this.hasOwnProperty('_glbl'), this.hasOwnProperty('something'));` at the bottom of `_create` and read about [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).